# Methods with multiple arguments iterating an array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have this method here:

```
boolean exibirAprovacao(double[][] codigoAluno, double[] codigoMateria, double nota) {
  boolean aprovaAluno = false;
  for(int i = 0; i < materia.length; i++) {
    materia[i] = codigoAluno;
    for(int j = 0; j < materia[i].length; j++) {
      materia[i][j] = codigoMateria;
      for(int k =0; k < materia[i][j].length; k++) {
        materia[i][j][k] = nota;
        if(materia[i][j][k] > 7.0) {
          aprovaAluno = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return aprovaAluno;
}
```

I'm supposed to call it giving three arguments, #1 student code, #2 subject code and #3 grade. I had declared them as "double" in the method, but Eclipse highlighted it as "cannot convert from double[] to double", so it suggested me to change from this:

```
boolean exibirAprovacao(double codigoAluno, double codigoMateria, double nota)
```

To this:

```
boolean exibirAprovacao(double[][] codigoAluno, double[] codigoMateria, double nota)
```

And now Eclipse gives me an error when I'm calling my method:

```
aluno01.exibirAprovacao(codigoAluno, codigoMateria, nota);
```

Stating that

> the method arguments are not applicable to the ones I'm passing

This is my array declaration:

```
double[][][] materia = new double[3][1][1];
```

This is an assignment that I have (starting Java + OO now). Any feedback is really appreciated.

Comment: What is this method supposed to do? To find a note? To perform a calculation? To fill in data?

Comment: It's supposed to iterate an array with a student's code, a "class" code and a grade. Then, it will check if the grade is >= 7 and return a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must review the logic of your program: If the method is supposed to *find out* if **a certain student** of **a certain grade** has aproved **a certain subject**, it should search one single value into the `materia` multi-array. I insist: It must **search** for a value, not **fill in** the data.

Second: Based upon the same assumption, to perform such a search, it would be enough if the method received **three single** parameters.

If Eclipse suggest you to change any method's firm, first understand what is the cause of the error. And do not accept suggestions without being aware of the implications (In this case, I'm afraid you shouldn't have accepted).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I got your point. I wanted to use it to populate data as I'd like to fill in dummy info. I guess I can populate the values of the multi-array in the main code and use the method just to return if the student passed the class. Does that sound right?

Comment: YES. That _does_ sound right. A good practice in programming is that each method must do _just one_ specific task. Therefore, you should code another specific method to populate the multi-array, and call it from the main method.